# Missing icons on top panel, dashboard applications, launcher

Tags: software-center, launcher, unity-dash, panel

So today I had trouble in an upgrade for Ubuntu when I accidentally shut down my laptop. I was able to log in and reset everything but I noticed that the icons on the top right panel are missing (network icon, volume, messages, even the icon launcher and my name). The only way I can switch off my device or even restart is by manually pressing the switch button of my laptop Only the clock has stayed. I tried looking for my settings but when I searched my dash home, none of my applications appeared. No calculator, no terminal etc. The only results that I got were the files I had saved. My upgrade manager have also disappeared.

I tried the unity reset command but nothing happened. Instead, my Google Chrome icon on my left panel disappeared and similarly, I cannot find it in my dash. I'm quite the novice when it comes to Ubuntu so any good step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would upgrading to 12.10 resolve this?

Comment: Does the *desktop* still work? Icons still there, you can create files there, get a menu by right-clicking?

Answer (score 0):

## No worries there is an possible solution

Since it is properly the Unity Desktop that got fiddled up I’d suggest trying to reinstall that.
Reinstall command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

## An Suggestion

Please tell me where it stopped at how much percent and when since there are properly some missing important packages or file you need to recover!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to remember where it stopped except for the "cleaning"" stage of the upgrade, and then I accidentally switched of my PC. Are there ways for me to find out where I stopped and see which packages I would need to recover?

Comment: Hi, while reinstalling ubuntu desktop I got the following error message:

/var/cache/apt/archives/libatk-adaptor-schemas_2.4.0-1ubuntu2_1386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Should I proceed installing Unity?